# How to get actual number of bytes written in BeginWrite/EndWrite?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, stream, httpwebrequest

I'm using `HttpWebRequest`'s `BeginWrite()` and `EndWrite()` to perform async writing to the web request. Though I can specify the number of bytes to be written in `BeginWrite()` call, the documentation suggests that this is the *maximum number of bytes* that will be written. How can I find the actual number of bytes that were written when I call `EndWrite()`?

Comment: Where does the HttpWebRequest class live? I cannot find a BeginWrite or EndWrite methods?

Comment: @Yacoub OP probably means the stream obtained from `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()`.